# Create Java application jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java

I have created a Java application in Eclipse, which needs `comm.jar` and `jexcel.jar` and `.property` files, so I have added them to libraries. I want to make a jar file out of my Java application, including the external jar files added to the application.

How can I do it? To run serial port programs I have copied `win32.dll` into `java_home/bin` and `comm.jar` into `java_home/jre/lib` and `javax.comm.properties` into `java_home/jre/lib`, but when delivering the product it should run only by needing the jre.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is not totally clear I suggest using the [Fat Jar Plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) should allow you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does this provide that the Executable Jar functionality doesn't have?

Comment: It just creates a big Jar file with everything (libs, properties, etc) in one file.

Comment: and provides a classloader which can be used to load the dependent jar files from inside the jar, which I believe is not default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can use File > Export > Executable Jar which includes all libraries.  There is also a checkbox to generate an ant build file as well as the jar in order to customize it further (I for instance make all the paths relative and remove the main-class flag).

Comment: yes,i have created jar as u told it is running but its not recognising any ports,i'm getting no such port exception

Comment: I can only imagine that is an error in your code - perhaps you reference a relative file path somewhere?  There shouldn't be any problem with the jar file that aren't in your code.

Comment: I can only imagine that is an error in your code - perhaps you reference a relative file path somewhere? There shouldn't be any problem with the jar file that aren't in your code.

Edit: Scratch that, I notice you're also loading DLLs, which may have to be explicitly specified as part of the build, which you have have to do with the Ant file.  I've not used DLLs in Java before, so I couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have two "path" issues. The Java Classpath and the path from which dlls are loaded.

If you were using a Java EE app server or OSGi then controlling these paths is addressed by the respective runtimes. Both Java EE and OSGi are likely to be overkill for small projects.

In which case you are delivering:

1. Your application JAR
2. The dependent jars
3. The DLLs

I suggest that on installing your app you place these artefacts into a suitable directory structure, for example .../myapp/lib  for the jars and .../myapp/bin for the dlls. Don't copy them into the infrastructure directories, for example the JRE lib and bin, or into Windows32 - that just leads to version nightmares and mysteries when someone installs a new jre.

Having got that structure, how to control the paths? For the classpath, look at the Manifest.mf file. [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/)

For the DLL path, I know of no good alternative to setting OS level environment variables ** before ** launching the JVM. Hence you need a little batch/shell script to launch your app, setting the PATH appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the project and say "Export". Now select "Java" in tree of choices. Under that select "Jar File". It'll guide you through the process and will allow you to export you project as a jar file.

Hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: This doesn't export the dependent libraries as well, however, so they would have to be manually refrenced at run time, which is what the asker is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The recently released Eclipse 3.5 has a Export as runnable Jar which allows to put all dependent jars in a subfolder to the jar file, and get the Manifest right.

It is an adaption of the FatJar plugin.  Works nicely!